# Why is my integer parameter being ignored/converted on this SOAP call?

Tags: xml, web-services, soap

I am making a call to a .Net WebService using this soap package...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <RunData xmlns="http://applecorepixels.com.au/dwwService/">
            <AccessCode xsi:type="xsd:int">6744</AccessCode>
        </RunData>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The call is being received ok, however, the **6744** parameter value is being received as **0** by the web service.

Initially, I was passing the parameter as just <AccessCode>6744</AccessCode> and thought the zero conversion was because the incoming integer parameter was being interpreted as a string, and added the xsd.

What is missing that will indicate the parameter is an integer?

Comment: You may be mistaken about the reason for the **0**. It is more likely a namespace problem causing the parameter to not be received, and thus to have the default value, **0**. Show us the web service header.

Comment: @John - Your comment caused me to look at the web service code, and I noticed the parameter was actually named iAccessCode, not AccessCode. So now it's working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the parameter name specified in the SOAP call is exactly the same as the parameter name in the Web Service.